# php calculate late fees every 30 days

Tags: php

ok, I am trying to figure out how to add 1.5% to a total number from my DB every 30 days. If my balance today is $600 and I have not paid it in 30 days, it adds 1.5%, but if I dont pay it in 60 days, it adds 1.5% on top of the first 30 days late fee. Here is what I have...

if ($invoicedate <= "$30_date"){ $late = (1.5 / 100) * $total; }

so I pull the date the invoice was created, check to see if it is 30 days or more and if so, calculates the correct "new" total as $late. How would I do this for every 30 days no matter how long? Do I really have to define $60_date, $90_date, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this ?

```
 $invoicedate = strtotime("2013/09/01");
 $TodayDate = strtotime('today');

 $timeDiff = abs($TodayDate - $invoicedate);

 $numberDays = $timeDiff/86400;  // 86400 seconds in one day

 $numberDays = intval($numberDays);

 $noOfdaysToCheck ="30";

 $total ="1000";

 if ($numberDays >= $noOfdaysToCheck){$late = (1.5 / 100) * $total; }
```

Every 30 days fees calc: Please update me, is this your expected one?

```
       $invoicedate = strtotime("2013/07/01");
       $TodayDate = strtotime('today');

       $timeDiff = abs($TodayDate - $invoicedate);

       $numberDays = $timeDiff/86400;  // 86400 seconds in one day

       $numberDays = intval($numberDays);

       $noOfdaysToCheck ="30";

       $Fees ="600";

       if ($numberDays >= $noOfdaysToCheck){

              $Interval = $numberDays%$noOfdaysToCheck;

              for($i=1;$i<=$Interval;$i++){
                     $late = (1.5 / 100) * $Fees;
                     $Fees =  FeesCalc($Fees);

               }
        }

       $Fees = number_format($Fees, 2, '.', '');
       echo $Fees;

       function FeesCalc($Fees){
            $late = (1.5 / 100) * $Fees;
            return $TotalFees = $late+$Fees;

       }
```

Comment: thanks but this just checks to see if it is past 30 days, I need it to do the 1.5% every 30 days. So for $600 after 30 days is $9, now I need it to after 60 days do another 1.5% on the $609

Comment: That is making an amount for $fees except if I set the invoicedate to 2013/11/01 then $fees is giving me $609 instead of $600 since it is not 30 days, it is only 1 day. If I set it to 2013/10/01 then it should be giving me the amount for 30 days but it is giving the amount for 60 days.

Comment: Updated the condition, please check now.

Comment: that is exactly right, thank you a million. it makes sense once I see it like this. Thanks for the teaching.

Comment: @KrishR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50771625/how-to-calculate-overdue-fees-every-month/50771766#50771766

Answer (score 0):

Every time in programming when you think you need to repeat variables in a certain way, what you really need to do is use a loop.

Assuming $invoicedate is a timestamp, also assuming you want to charge monthly, not after 30 days:

```
$lateMonths = 1;
$late = $total;
while ($invoicedate <= strtotime(date('Y-m-d') . ' - '.$lateMonths . 'month')){
    $late = 101.5 * $late;
}
```

Comment: ok, seems logical. Each time I run what you have above, it just times out the website for some reason. $invoicedate=20131001

Comment: well maybe $invoicedate > time()

Comment: for some reason, this snippet just hangs the webpage.

Comment: here is what I used...while ($invoicedate > time() . ' - '.$lateMonths . 'month')