# How to calculate overdue fee's every month

Tags: php

I am having a problem with overdue calculation because I don't know how to get the month interval of the date I set.

I want to add 3% to the remaining balance when the date today reaches the overdue date.

Here is my code:

```html
<?php 
 $balance = $fetch['total'] - $total;
 $loan_date = strtotime($fetch['loan_end']);
 $TodayDate = strtotime('today');
  
  <!--plus 3% to the remaining for every month exceeds to loan_date then print the balance below-->
 
 print number_format($balance);
  
  
?>
```

Here is my example interval for every 30 days exceed to loan_end

```html
       $invoicedate = strtotime("2013/07/01");
       $TodayDate = strtotime('today');

       $timeDiff = abs($TodayDate - $invoicedate);

       $numberDays = $timeDiff/86400;  // 86400 seconds in one day

       $numberDays = intval($numberDays);

       $noOfdaysToCheck ="30";

       $Fees ="600";

       if ($numberDays >= $noOfdaysToCheck){

              $Interval = $numberDays%$noOfdaysToCheck;

              for($i=1;$i<=$Interval;$i++){
                     $late = (1.5 / 100) * $Fees;
                     $Fees =  FeesCalc($Fees);

               }
        }

       $Fees = number_format($Fees, 2, '.', '');
       echo $Fees;

       function FeesCalc($Fees){
            $late = (1.5 / 100) * $Fees;
            return $TotalFees = $late+$Fees;

       }
```

It calculates the fee for every 30 days exceeding. now in my code I want to calculate (add 3+ to the balance) every month exceeding to loan end.

Comment: What are you defining as a 'month'?

Comment: a month after the loan_end

Comment: Yes, but is a month a calendar month, 4 weeks, or 30 days?

Comment: @JonathanEltgroth I need calculation not date

Comment: I will show example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code:

```html
<?php
 $balance = $fetch['total'] - $total;
 $endDate = new DateTime($fetch['loan_end']);
 $today = new DateTime();

 if($today >=$endDate)
  {
   $interval = $endDate->diff(new DateTime());
                        $months = round(abs($interval->y * 12 + $interval->m + $interval->d / 30));
   for($i=1;$i<=$months;$i++){
   $late = (3 / 100) * $balance;
   $balance = FeesCalc($balance);
   }
  }

 print number_format($balance);
  
  function FeesCalc($balance){
     $late = (3 / 100) * $balance;
     return $TotalFees = $late+$balance;
   }

?>
```

Comment: This is what I am talking about :D thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `strtotime()`, use PHP's DateTime objects instead. They have a built in method to calculate the number of months between two objects:

```
<?php

$balance = $fetch['total'] - $total;
$endDate = new DateTime( $fetch['loan_end'] );
$diff    =  $endDate->diff( new DateTime() );
$months  = round( abs($diff->y * 12 + $diff->m + $diff->d / 30) );

$base    = $balance * 0.03;

$interest = $base * $months;

echo number_format( $interest + $balance );
```

Please note that this function assumes `$fetch['loan_end']` is a MySQL `DATE` field (i.e. `2014-07-01`, for example).

Comment: Almost there. But what I want to happen is add 3% only when the date today = $fetch['loan_end']. And add 3% for another month exceed to loan_end.

Comment: there must be if($endDate>=$today) somthing like that